# C Modules On Windows Need Linux System Inclusion

Tags: c, windows, unix, eclipse-cdt

I am new to C programming (proficient in Java) trying to compile some old (~1999) C modules on my windows machine.  I'm using Eclipse CDT with Cygwin installed on my computer.  I have resolved all of my issues except one: the modules have include statements for things like sys/io.h, sys/stat.h etc.  After doing some research I found that these are unix system calls.  Is it possible to use Cygwin to get these inclusions resolved on my windows machine through eclipse?  Or do I need to run on a unix environment?  Please correct me if any of this information is wrong... I'm at my wits end trying to compile these modules.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use Cygwin, Mingw or other GCC-like compilers on Windows (with or without Eclipse) - it still is Windows and does not provide 100% compatible Linux system services. So YMMV.

Windows 10 with [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) provides much more compatible Linux environment and also a real Linux C compiler, with all its include files. If you need to just run some Linux program without spending much effort to Windows adaptation, this is the way.